# Долгий ответ (вывод данных) ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

еще плохо знаю js, прошу посмотреть участки кода js и php, и не плеваться, а помочь советом, подсказать где исправить ошибки, что бы ускорить работу скрипта, или же что напрочь убрать.

Это виджет поддержки (знаю про сокеты, но нагрузки на этот модуль пока нет, да и опыта такого тоже), при отправке по клику в виджете сообщения пользователю, сообщение появляеться спустя 1 - 1.5 секунды, что визуально долго, и знаю сайты где чат реализован так же с аяксом, но визуальная отправка моментальная.

Прошу помочь мне с этим вопросом
Всем спасибо!

Код js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                          function send_supportWidget()
                          {
                          //Получаю параметры
                          var author_type = '{{ chat.author_type ==  user ? '-left' : '-right' }}';
                           author_type_img = '{{ chat.author_type ==  'user' ? '/templates/backend/img/support.png' : user.getAvatar() }}';
                           author_type_usr = '{{ chat.author_type == 'user' ? 'Support' : user.getDisplayName() }}';
                           author_message = '{{ processPic(chat.body) }}';

                           body = $("#textInput").val()
                           var body_div ='<div class="chat-message '+ author_type +'"> <div class="chat-message-avatar"> <img src="'+ author_type_img +'" alt="" class="chat-avatar -small"> </div> <div class="chat-message-text"> '+ body +' </div>';
                            // и отправляю
                                 $.ajax({
                                          type: "POST",
                                          url: "/support/sendMessage_widget",
                                          data: {body: body},
                                          success: function(response) { //Данные отправлены успешно
                                            if (body === "") {
                                              send__error();
                                            } else {
                                                    var author_message = '{{ chat.time }}';
                                                    document.getElementById("textInput").value = "";

                                                    $('.chat-messages-content').append(body_div);

                                                    document.getElementById('chat-messages-content').scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'end' });

                                                    }
                                                },
                                                error: function(response) { 
                                                  send__error();
                                                }


                                  });

                          };
                          function send__error(){

                            Swal.fire({
                              type: 'error',
                              timer: 2000,
                              title: 'Ошибка отправки сообщения',
                              text: 'Поле ввода текста пусто, или же ошибка подключение к сети Интернет',
                              onBeforeOpen: () => {
                                  Swal.showLoading()
                                  timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
                                    Swal.getContent().querySelector('b')
                                      .textContent = Swal.getTimerLeft()
                                  }, 2400)
                                },
                                onClose: () => {
                                  clearInterval(timerInterval)
                                }
                              }).then((result) => {
                                if (
                                  /* Read more about handling dismissals below */
                                  result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.timer
                                ) {
                                }
                            });
                            return false;
                            }                    
                        </script>
```

Код с контроллера

```
<?php
```

class controller_support_supportwidget extends controller
{

```
function main__widget()
{
    $this->_template = 'support__widget.tpl';

    $user = user::i()->getUser();
    $support_list = model_support::getList($user['id']);

    $this->assign('chat_list', $support_list);
    $this->assign('user', $user);

    model_support::setRead();
}

function sendMessage_widget()
{
    $result2 = false;

    $imager = new imager('support');
    $picture = $imager->process('picture');

    if($picture)
        $result2 = model_support::setMessage('<img>/m/support/'.$picture.'</img>');

    $text = $_POST['body'];
    $result = model_support::setMessage($text);

    if($result || $result2)
    {
        user::i()->setFlash('send_message_success');
    }
    else
    {
        user::i()->setFlash('send_message_error', array('error_code' => $result));
    }
    exit();
}
```

}

Код с модели модуля

```
    public static function setMessage($text, $user_id = false, $author_type = 'user', $color = '')
{

    if(!$user_id)
    {
        $user = user::i()->getUser();
        $user_id = $user['id'];
    }
    else
    {
        $user = model_user::getById($user_id);
    }

    $readed = ($author_type == 'user') ? 1 : 0;

    if(trim($text) == '')
        return false;

    $new_message = database::i()->support()->insert(array(
        'body' => $text,
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'author_type' => $author_type,
        'readed' => $readed,
        'created_at' => time(),
        'additional_color' => $color
    ));

    if($author_type == 'manager')
    {
        $maildata = array(
            'text' => $text
        );

        model_mail_query::add(
            config::i()->get('app/mail_from'),      // from
            $user['login'],                         // to
            'Получен ответ от поддержки',           // subject
            'support',                              // template
            $maildata                               // data
        );
    }

    return $new_message;
}

              <script type="text/javascript">
                              function send_supportWidget()
                              {
                              //Получаю параметры
                              var author_type = '{{ chat.author_type ==  user ? '-left' : '-right' }}';
                               author_type_img = '{{ chat.author_type ==  'user' ? '/templates/backend/img/support.png' : user.getAvatar() }}';
                               author_type_usr = '{{ chat.author_type == 'user' ? 'Support' : user.getDisplayName() }}';
                               author_message = '{{ processPic(chat.body) }}';

                               body = $("#textInput").val()
                               var body_div ='<div class="chat-message '+ author_type +'"> <div class="chat-message-avatar"> <img src="'+ author_type_img +'" alt="" class="chat-avatar -small"> </div> <div class="chat-message-text"> '+ body +' </div>';
                                // и отправляю
                                     $.ajax({
                                              type: "POST",
                                              url: "/support/sendMessage_widget",
                                              data: {body: body},
                                              success: function(response) { //Данные отправлены успешно
                                                if (body === "") {
                                                  send__error();
                                                } else {
                                                        var author_message = '{{ chat.time }}';
                                                        document.getElementById("textInput").value = "";

                                                        $('.chat-messages-content').append(body_div);

                                                        document.getElementById('chat-messages-content').scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'end' });

                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    error: function(response) { 
                                                      send__error();
                                                    }


                                      });

                              };
                              function send__error(){

                                Swal.fire({
                                  type: 'error',
                                  timer: 2000,
                                  title: 'Ошибка отправки сообщения',
                                  text: 'Поле ввода текста пусто, или же ошибка подключение к сети Интернет',
                                  onBeforeOpen: () => {
                                      Swal.showLoading()
                                      timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
                                        Swal.getContent().querySelector('b')
                                          .textContent = Swal.getTimerLeft()
                                      }, 2400)
                                    },
                                    onClose: () => {
                                      clearInterval(timerInterval)
                                    }
                                  }).then((result) => {
                                    if (
                                      /* Read more about handling dismissals below */
                                      result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.timer
                                    ) {
                                    }
                                });
                                return false;
                                }                    
                            </script>
```

```html
<div class="message"></div>

<div class="chat-widget" id="chatWidget">

  <!-- chat toggle -->
  <input id="chat-widget-toggle" class="chat-widget-toggle" type="checkbox">

  <!-- chat close button --> 
  <label title="close chat" for="chat-widget-toggle" class="chat-widget-button chat-close-button">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" version="1.1" height="64" viewBox="0 0 64 64" enable-background="new 0 0 64 64">
  <g>
    <path fill="#1D1D1B" d="M28.941,31.786L0.613,60.114c-0.787,0.787-0.787,2.062,0,2.849c0.393,0.394,0.909,0.59,1.424,0.59   c0.516,0,1.031-0.196,1.424-0.59l28.541-28.541l28.541,28.541c0.394,0.394,0.909,0.59,1.424,0.59c0.515,0,1.031-0.196,1.424-0.59   c0.787-0.787,0.787-2.062,0-2.849L35.064,31.786L63.41,3.438c0.787-0.787,0.787-2.062,0-2.849c-0.787-0.786-2.062-0.786-2.848,0   L32.003,29.15L3.441,0.59c-0.787-0.786-2.061-0.786-2.848,0c-0.787,0.787-0.787,2.062,0,2.849L28.941,31.786z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
  </label>

  <div class="chat-box">
    <!-- chat user info     -->
    <div class="chat-avatar-box">
      <img class="chat-avatar"   
           src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/30/17/27/business-woman-2697954_960_720.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div class="chat-message-box">
      <!--  chat header -->
      <div class="chat-header">
        <h1 class="chat-title">
          <span class="chat-title-primary">Чат Поддержки (тут имя проекта)</span>
          <span class="chat-title-sub">Мы ответим Вам в ближайшее время</span>
        </h1>
      </div>

      <!--   chat message  -->
      <div class="chat-messages">
         <div id="chat-messages-content" class="chat-messages-content">
          {% if chat_list %}
            {% for chat in chat_list %}
            <div class="chat-message {{ chat.author_type ==  'user' ? '-right' : '-left' }}">
                <div class="chat-message-avatar">
                  <img src="{{ chat.author_type ==  'user' ? chat.user.getAvatar() : '/templates/backend/img/support.png' }}" alt="" class="chat-avatar -small">
                </div>
                <div class="chat-message-text">
                  {{ processPic(chat.body) }}
                </div>
            </div>
              {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
            <div class="chat-message-text">
              <p class="text-muted text-center">
                <br>У вас пока нет сообщений<br>
              </p>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- chat input box  -->
      <div class="chat-form-box">
        <form class="chat-form" id="chat-form ajaxStart" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div id="chat__form-inner" class="chat__form-inner">
          <span class="input-group-append">
            <a href="#" onclick="$('.addfile').slideToggle(); return false;" class=""><i class="fas fa-images"></i></a>
          </span>
          <textarea id="textInput" type="text" name="body" class="form-control chat-form-input" 
               placeholder="Введите Ваше сообщение.." required></textarea>
         <button id="send" title="send message" onclick="send_supportWidget(); return false;" type="submit" class="chat-form-button">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" 
                 width="535.5px" height="535.5px" 
                 viewBox="0 0 535.5 535.5" 
                 style="enable-background:new 0 0 535.5 535.5;">
              <polygon points="0,497.25 535.5,267.75 0,38.25 0,216.75 382.5,267.75 0,318.75"/>
            </svg>
          </button>
          </div>
          <div class="row addfile" style="margin-top:10px; display:none;">
           <div class="col-sm-12">
             <div class="form-group" style="text-align: center;">
               <input type="file" name="picture" class="" style="">
             </div>
           </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- chat open button -->
  <label title="open chat" for="chat-widget-toggle" class="chat-widget-button chat-open-button">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 60 60" style="enable-background:new 0 0 60 60;" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
      <path d="M54.072,2.535L19.93,2.465c-3.27,0-5.93,2.66-5.93,5.93v3.124l26.065-0.054c4.377,0,7.935,3.557,7.935,7.929v21.142   c0,0.634-0.083,1.248-0.224,1.84l3.484,3.833c0.193,0.213,0.464,0.327,0.74,0.327c0.121,0,0.243-0.021,0.36-0.067   c0.386-0.148,0.64-0.52,0.64-0.933v-10h1.07c3.27,0,5.93-2.66,5.93-5.93V8.465C60,5.195,57.34,2.535,54.072,2.535z" />
      <path d="M40.069,13.465L5.93,13.535c-3.27,0-5.93,2.66-5.93,5.93v21.141c0,3.27,2.66,5.93,5.929,5.93H12v10   c0,0.413,0.254,0.784,0.639,0.933c0.118,0.046,0.24,0.067,0.361,0.067c0.276,0,0.547-0.114,0.74-0.327l9.704-10.675l16.626-0.068   c3.27,0,5.93-2.66,5.93-5.93V19.394C46,16.124,43.34,13.465,40.069,13.465z M12,34.449c-2.206,0-4-1.794-4-4s1.794-4,4-4   s4,1.794,4,4S14.206,34.449,12,34.449z M23,34.449c-2.206,0-4-1.794-4-4s1.794-4,4-4s4,1.794,4,4S25.206,34.449,23,34.449z    M34,34.449c-2.206,0-4-1.794-4-4s1.794-4,4-4s4,1.794,4,4S36.206,34.449,34,34.449z" />
    </g>
    </svg>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Поменяйте немного логику. При отправке сообщения - добавляйте его сразу на страницу, не ждите ответа от сервера. При успешном ответе сервера - ничего не делайте, при не успешном, можно на странице показать, что сообщение не отправлено и дать возможность отправить его снова. В таком случае, визуально все будет работать мгновенно.

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо за ответ, попробую таким образом.
А то, что сам запрос происходит так долго это ведь так же не верно?

Comment: Запрос может происходить долго по очень многим причинам. Слабая сеть, слабый сервак, плохо настроена БД, не оптимизирована таблица. По приведенному коду почти невозможно узнать, в чем может быть причина.

Comment: Да, я это понимаю, думал может просто кто явные ошибки увидит в коде